# Dynamic Styling of Angular Material Select Form Control

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using Angular Materials in a project and I am trying to do some dynamic styling of a mat-select form control to fulfill a requirement.

I want to override the default colors on some of the selector elements and also change these to another color when a selection has been confirmed (see picture below). I have got it partially working, but I do not know if it is the best approach. I am using the ::ng-deep selector to get to the applicable DOM elements (pieced together from some examples I found online). It works and I am able to apply custom style to the elements. I know the ::ng-deep selector i deprecated, but not sure how to do this otherwise.

To do the color change I have wrapped the form field in a container where I use ngClass with a conditional statement to override the "default" colors. The problem with doing this is that the custom styles for the .mat-select-panel element is no longer working.

Any input on how to get this working, and perhaps a better approach than using the ::ng-deep selector is greatly appreshiated.

[image]

**.ts**

```
<div class="table-select-selection" 

  [ngClass]="{'table-select-selection-success': (!selectingTable && selectionSuccessful)}"
  
>

  <h3 class="mat-subheading-2">Select Sheet</h3>

  <mat-form-field appearance="standard">

    <mat-label>Worksheets</mat-label>

    <mat-select panelClass="dialog-selection-box" [(ngModel)]="tableName" (ngModelChange)="onTableChange()">

        <mat-option *ngFor="let table of tableNames" [value]="table">

            {{ table }}

        </mat-option>

    </mat-select>

  </mat-form-field>
  
</div>
```

**.scss**

```
.table-select {

    &-selection {

        ::ng-deep {

            $details-color: rgb(168, 168, 168);
    
            .mat-form-field-infix {
    
                font-size: 16px;
                padding-left: 5px !important;
    
            }
    
            .mat-select-arrow {
    
                color: $details-color !important;
    
            }
    
            .mat-select-panel {
    
                .mat-option[aria-selected="true"] {
                    
                    color: $details-color !important;
    
                }
    
                .mat-option-text:hover {
    
                    font-weight: bold !important;
    
                } 
    
            }
    
            .mat-form-field {
    
                width: 100%;
    
                .mat-input-element {
                    color: $details-color !important;
                }
                .mat-form-field-label {
                    color: $details-color !important;
                    margin: 5px;
                }
                .mat-form-field-underline {
                    background-color: $details-color !important;
                }
                .mat-form-field-ripple {
                    background-color: $details-color !important;
                }

            }
    
        }

        &-success {

            ::ng-deep {

                $details-color: green;
        
                .mat-form-field-infix {
        
                    background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.25);
        
                }
        
                .mat-select-arrow {
        
                    color: $details-color !important;
        
                }
        
                .mat-form-field {
        
                    .mat-input-element {
                        color: $details-color !important;
                    }
                    .mat-form-field-label {
                        color: $details-color !important;
                    }
                    .mat-form-field-underline {
                        background-color: $details-color !important;
                    }
                    .mat-form-field-ripple {
                        background-color: $details-color !important;
                    }

                }
        
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Anyone have an answer for this? I also have the same question.